# c#.net clear dataGridView contents from another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to connect a button in the form2 with dataGridView in the form1 at c# language
indeed, I need to control a form content from another one ?
how the code should be ?

in vb 6.0 I just use form2.text1.text = "" and it works well but here it's not

for example code in c# I need to do this but from another form: dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

Comment: You cannot do it in C# until you have same instance of `Form1` and `DataGridView` modifier is set to `Public`

Comment: thank you so much, but what do you mean by same instance of Form1?

Comment: Just pass the current instance of Form1 in the constructor of Form2. Add your code in the question. It will easy to tell what you need to add in that.